# SparkNLP, Tensorflow, Pytorch for NLP

Tags: natural-language, spark-mllib

I used Tensorflow, Keras and Pytorch in the past for NLP related works. New company uses Hadoop, which I only have basic concepts. I looked around and found the NLP package associated with the distributed environment is called SparkNLP. I wonder do I need to give up using SparkNLP instead of Tensorflow, Pytorch to fully transit to SparkNLP to dofor NLP modeling in Hadoop from now on?

My largest confusion is on what would be the best/better practice setting up a model using data in hadoop. as i have never modeled in such environment(except queried some data out in the past), i try to get a sense what are the steps i should do when i started working with hadoop data and building the model.

Comment: I never used SparkNLP but it’s like comparing lego’s to toy car, isn’t it? With TensorFlow or PyTorch you can build any model, the Spark thing gives you just a collection of models to choose from.

Comment: @Tim thanks for reply. The part i am confused most i guess is on what would the best practice to build ML models on hadoop (as i have never done one before). I know hadoop does distributed computation, so i assume sparkNLP works best for this style. But i am still not too sure what will happen if using tensorflow. it looks not so easy to set up based on my reading so far. but honestly still blur images in my head. would be appreciated if you have some recommendations for best practice building models using hadoop data.

Comment: First question I would ask is if you actually need Hadoop? In most cases the answer is no, you just need a machine with more RAM, or maybe even not.

Comment: @Tim that's a fair question, honestly all i know so far is the company i am gonna work for is large with hadoop and has all their data on it. That's why I am a bit struggle what to do when i start modeling.